# How to detect that QGIS is shutting down in a plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I built a plugin in QGIS and needs to stop it when user wants to exit to remove signals and close properly. How can I get an event when QGIS is exiting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When QGIS closes, the plugin's `unload()` method is called as documented in https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#mainplugin-py

This means that you don't have to detect anything yourself. QGIS takes care of unloading the plugins.

Comment: Thanks for this anwer. Problem is that my plugin add several signals to detect objects modification and I noticed that if I don"t remove them, I get a minidump crash when closing. This doesn't occur if I disconnect signal before closing. So it could be possible to modify standard unload to call mine but this complicates installation.

Comment: looking deeper, you're right, it was my unload procedure which is wrong and called by qgis.